# c# last insert id

Tags: c#, object, casting, insert

I'm using a stored procedure with this sql:

```
INSERT INTO [dbTblUsers]([strUsername], [strPassword])
VALUES (@p1,@p2);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

And calling the procedure:

```
// Insert new user
nId = daUsers.InsertQuery(textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
// Insert new Twitter OAuth
daTwitterOAuth.Insert(nId, textBoxConsumerKey.Text, textBoxConsumerSecret.Text, textBoxToken.Text, textBoxTokenSecret.Text);
```

How do I cast the object @@IDENTITY int the int nId?
Like this?

```
nId = (int)daUsers.InsertQuery(textBoxUsername.Text, textBoxPassword.Text);
```

Comment: Have you configured the returned identity as an output parameter of the stored procedure? it might help if we could see the full stored procedure definition.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, don't use `@@IDENTTY` - use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`; the first can give you unexpected answers if there are any triggers involved. Secondly; both of these return decimals; cast it at the call-site, IMO:

```
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)
```

Comment: I couldn't use scope_id, it was sqlce but I've sorted it now. Thanks anyway.